# Flickr8 dataset image data augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, tf.keras

I am using the Flickr8 dataset for image captioning. my problem is overfitting and I realized one of the ways of solving it is image data augmentation.
I do not know how to correctly separate train and test datasets using image data generator in Keras. in my dataset, I have no subclasses and when I run the code below I get the following statement: "Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes."

```
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=0.2)

train_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                                 directory=image_path,
                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                 target_size=(280, 280),
                                                 subset="training",
                                                 )


validation_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                                 directory=image_path,
                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                 target_size=(280, 280),
                                                 subset="validation",
                                                 )
I would really appreciate it if you could help me to find the solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

TheImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory expects to see subdirectories which are the classes. If it doesn't find them then it returns the message you received. If you have only 1 class then make a subdirectory in you image_path directory, call it say class_1. Then put all you images into that directory